Colon and semicolon use in a list of questions in APA style
I'm wondering the correct punctuation in a list of questions within an academic APA setting. For instance, if I had:

We were still able to address our original questions: How did the students respond to the changing curriculum? How was the faculty able to form a common ground on the changes?

Would it be appropriate to put a semicolon between the questions? Is that necessary? Should the colon be an emdash in the first place?
Thanks very much.

You mean question mark and semicolon?; Like that?; Hope not. Seems clear as is.

Your current sentence correctly follows APA style guidelines.
In academic writing, especially within the APA style, the punctuation in a list of questions like the one you provided does not include a semicolon between the questions.
You can use either a colon or an em dash to introduce the list. In this context, a colon is more appropriate.
